# collection count increasing after sharding mongodb

Tags: mongodb, cluster-computing, sharding

I am not able to understand why collection count increasing after sharding mongodb.

I have a collection of 20M records , when I sharded collection count keep increasing , plz help me out

clusture configration

3 shards
3 config sever
6 query routers

Comment: You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful, too, despite it's harsh title.

Answer (score 3):

If I get it right, you mean that `db.shardedCollection.count()`returns more documents than you expect. This is a [known bug (SERVER-3645)](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3645).

### TL;DR

The problem is that the way sharding works, it *can* happen that after a chunk migration so called [orphaned documents](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/#term-orphaned-document) exist. These are documents which exist as a duplicate on a shard not responsible for the key range that the document falls into. For almost all practical purposes, this is not a problem, since the `mongos` takes care of "sorting them out" (which is a bit simplified, but sufficient in this context).

However, when calling a `db.collection.count()` on a sharded collection, this query gets routed to all shards, since it does not contain the shard key.

> **Disclaimer** from here on, it is my theory, deduced from the observed behavior

Since the orphaned documents still technically exist on a shard, they seem to get counted and the result of the count as a whole is reported back to the mongos, which simply sums up all the results. I assume `.count()` to take a shortcut on the individual shard, possibly simply counting the entries of the `_id` index for performance reasons.

### Workaround

As written in the ticket, using an aggregation mitigates the problem:

```
db.collection.aggregate({$group:{_id:"uniqueDocs",count:{$sum:1}}})
```

However, this aggregation is not ideal, and should show better performance when changed as below if you have a shard key other than `_id`

```
db.books.aggregate([
    { $project:{ _id:0, yourShardKey: 1 }},
    { $group:{ _id:"uniqueDocs", count:{ $sum:1 }}}
])
```

or

```
db.books.aggregate([
    { $project:{ _id:1 }},
    { $group:{ _id:"uniqueDocs", count:{ $sum:1 }}}
])
```

if you use `_id` as your shard key.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this z the same I was expecting , but thanks for making me confident now